# single word noun for "whole" as opposed to parts/components?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a good single word noun for referring to the "whole" in a part-whole relationship?

I'm looking for a noun with a clear connotation that suggests this **thing** is made up of parts and/or components (without actual mention of parts etc.). I looked up synonyms of "whole" as a noun in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/whole), and got the following:

> aggregate, full, sum, summation, sum total, total, totality

But they sound too abstract (just like the words "whole" or "entirety").

I also thought about the word "System", but it seems to imply too much (a complex system with structures and hierarchies etc.)

Is there a good word that's more concrete than the above-mentioned synonyms, but does not overkill as words such as "system", "organization" etc.?

Comment: You might also shy away from **conglomerate**, which [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conglomerate) defines: << noun  1 A thing consisting of a number of different and distinct parts or items that are grouped together.

_the Earth is a specialized conglomerate of organisms_ >>. It is hardly in an informal register, but there _is_ the broadening encouraged by the business usage.

Comment: *Whole* is already a single-word noun with the meaning you describe.

Comment: *Aggregate* is good in a technical context, as is *assembly* (particularly as *the [something] assembly*. *Composite* or *the composite whole* might just work, but isn't as idiomatic.

Comment: **assembly** noun (Plural **assemblies**) **3.1** *[count noun]* A unit consisting of components that have been fitted together. *‘the tail assembly of the aircraft’* https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assembly  See also: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/assembly.html

Comment: Can you share the specific subject of your definition? What is “the thing”? There are often subject specific terms you might find helpful; such as a mass, a biome, a collection, a collective, a network, an amalgamation, etc.

Comment: I agree with Lawrence and anyway, why is Merriam-Webster your only source?Did no other dictionaries or search engines have anything useful to say?

Comment: **Context is everything. Resistance is futile**. For Pete's sake.

Answer (score 0):

**Structure** seems to be the word you are looking for, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/structure) gives, among others, the following definitions:

> *the arrangement of particles or parts in a substance or body* (examples: *soil structure, molecular structure*)
>
> *organization of parts as dominated by the general character of the whole* (examples: *economic structure, personality structure*)
>
> *the aggregate of elements of an entity in their relationships to each other* (example: *the structure of a language*)

*Structure* does not imply complexity, in fact the word is used as *data structure* in [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) to describe (according to the Wikipedia link):

> a collection of data values, the relationships among them, and the functions or operations that can be applied to the data

Examples of *data structures* are (also according to the Wikipedia link):

> arrays, (linked) lists, records, etc.

These structures are by no means complex, but do imply they contain *data*, which I think is equivalent to the *parts* or *components* in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Among the possible options could be:

[set](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set) (ODO)

> noun
>         **1** A group or collection of things that belong together or resemble one another or are usually found together.

**syn**. assemblage; system; organization; combination; complex; whole; integral; setup; aggregate/ aggregation;

[unit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unit) (ODO)

> noun
>         **1** An individual thing or person regarded as single and complete but which can also form an individual component of a larger or more complex whole.

(especially when the "whole" could itself possibly be a part of a larger system).

"[Hardware Unit](ftp://ftp.tu-clausthal.de/pub/institute/informatik/v-modell-xt/Releases/1.2.1.1/Documentation/HTML/16cf6f89dd7fcd8.html): A »Hardware Unit will be realized by integrating »Hardware Components."

Answer (score -1):

Union. "something that is made one : something formed by a combining or coalition of parts or members. MW

Hard won, the union will stand.

Comment: https://youtu.be/QHuA8WXBNAs